# How do I handle Many-To-One Relationships with Spring Boot + MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm learning how to use MongoDB with spring boot (Spring data MondoDB).

In my current code base that uses PostgreSQL, I have an API `GET /api/orders/238392`, which returns a model as follows:

```
{
    "orderId":238392,
    "status":"FULFILLED",
    "senNumber":"AB8893920",
    "customer":{
        "customerId":"lskj2409023471lskdjflsf",
        "name":"John Doe",
        "email":"john.doe@acme.com",
        "phoneNumber":"7326585306",
        "city":"Los Angeles"
    }
}
```

I now want to implement this user-case with MongoDB in the backend. This is my model

```
// Orders.java
@Data
@Document
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long orderId;
    private String status;
    private String senNumber;
    private Customer customer;
}


//Customer.java
@Data
@Document
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String customerId;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String city;
}
```

My API now works fine. However, I have a problem with the relationship between Orders and Customers.
In a relational world, I had the `@ManyToOne` on `customer`, as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
private Customer customer;
```

I cannot do this in Mongo (that's where I need help).

Now, to my question. I have two collections - **Customer** and **Order**. Both of them have CRUD APIs. How do I handle a ManyToOne relationship between Order and Customer.

***If a user updates some properties of a Customer (name, email, etc), how does that change reflect in the Orders document?***

I have the following options that come to my mind:

1. When I update a customer, I can update all the order documents with the new customer details (this doesn't seem correct - might cause a lot of performance overhead, i feel)
2. Using something like `@DbRef` - if that's the case, can I get some links to related documents or references.
3. Came across a library called `RelMongo` that allows you to use `@ManyToOne` annotations just like how you would in a relational world.

This could be a simple *best-practices* question, I'm not sure. However, any help goes a long way to improve my understanding!!

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following relationship: one customer can have many orders. For the API that you provided `GET /api/orders/238392`, you should reference the customer_id in each order that you have.

If you have a route that has the following property: `GET /api/customer/123/orders` which will return you all the orders of the customer then you should keep track of the orders of the customer by having an array of reference to the orderId.

Also `@ManyToOne and @OneToMany` is equivalent to `@DBRef`.

Here is a good blog post that will help you choose the right schema design for your use case:
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3

Comment: You really opened a door for me! Thanks! I went through the article, and changed my model to use a @DBRef for the customer, and it worked perfectly for my use case.